# setTimeout function to play an audio after certain time Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue-audio for an audio player in Vue.js. I have AudioPlayer component.
**My code:**

```
<template>
  <vue-audio id = "myAudio" :file= "file1"/>
</template>

<script>
import VueAudio from 'vue-audio';

export default {
  props: {
    file1: String,
  },
  components: {
    'vue-audio': VueAudio,
  },
  mounted (){
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('myAudio').play()
        }, 3000);
  },
  name: 'AudioPlayer',
};
</script>
```

I encounter an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).play is not a
>   function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ref` to reference to current Vue component.
As checking [source code](https://github.com/shershen08/vuejs-sound-player/blob/798d94e4c0b7568e6df8d639a4514f3a0d79ad49/src/vueaudio.plugin.js#L145), we can use `getAudio` to get current audio component

```
<template>
  <vue-audio id = "myAudio" :file= "file1" ref="currentAudio" />
</template>

<script>
import VueAudio from 'vue-audio';

export default {
  props: {
    file1: String,
  },
  components: {
    'vue-audio': VueAudio,
  },
  mounted (){
      var self = this
      setTimeout(function() {
        self.$refs.currentAudio.getAudio().play()
      }, 3000);
  },
  name: 'AudioPlayer',
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `ref` attribute to the element instead.

```
<template>
  <vue-audio id = "myAudio" :file= "file1" ref="myAudio" />
</template>

<script>
import VueAudio from 'vue-audio';

export default {
  props: {
    file1: String,
  },
  components: {
    'vue-audio': VueAudio,
  },
  mounted (){
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.$refs.myAudio.play()
      }, 3000);
  },
  name: 'AudioPlayer',
};
</script>
```